# Calling getContentAsPDF() within a Flow generates empty PDF

Tags: visualforce, visual-workflow, pdf

I created a screen flow that calls an `@InvocableMethod` method that renders a Case as a PDF using `getContentAsPDF()`, then sends the PDF to the Case Contact.  The PDF is generated when I run it in an anonymous window within the org outside of the flow.  However, when I run the code in the flow, the PDF attachment is blank.  The user I'm running the code as has access to the Visualforce page and the Apex class.  Is calling `getContentAsPDF()` not allowed from within a flow?

```
public with sharing class sendCaseViaEmail {

    @InvocableMethod(Label='Email Case Details')
    public static List<Response> doIt(List<Request> requests) {

        System.debug('requests: ' + requests);

        List<Response> responses = new List<Response>();

        for(Request request : requests) {

            sendEmail(request.caseId);

            Response response = new Response();
            response.sent = true;

            responses.add(response);
        }

        return responses;

    }

    public static void sendEmail(String caseId) {

        System.debug('caseId: ' + caseId);

        try {

            Case caseObj = [Select Id, CaseNumber, OwnerId, Priority, ContactEmail from Case where Id = :caseId];

            if(caseObj.ContactEmail == null) {
                return;
            }

            System.debug('contactEmail: ' + caseObj.ContactEmail);

            // create a virtual page
            PageReference page = new PageReference('/apex/caseDetails');
            // add our record id
            page.getParameters().put('id', caseId);
            // generate and PDF blob
            // You can save this blob as a file, document, or attachment!
            Blob reportPdf = page.getContentAsPDF();

            // Create email
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            message.setToAddresses(new String[]{ caseObj.ContactEmail });
            //message.setToAddresses(new String[]{ 'msobczak@salesforce.com' });
            message.setBccAddresses(new String[]{ 'msobczak@salesforce.com' });
            message.setSubject('Deviation ' + caseObj.CaseNumber + ' Complete Evaluation');
            message.setHtmlBody('Full details of Deviation ' + caseObj.CaseNumber + ' are attached.');

            // Attach PDF to email and send
            Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
            attachment.setContentType('application/pdf');
            attachment.setFileName('Case' + caseObj.CaseNumber + '.pdf');
            attachment.setInline(false);
            attachment.setBody(reportPdf);
            message.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[]{ attachment });
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{ message });

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.debug('Exception: ' + e.getMessage());
            System.debug('Line # ' + e.getLineNumber());
        }
    }

    public class Request {

        @InvocableVariable(Required=true)
        public String caseId;

    }

    public class Response {

        @InvocableVariable
        public Boolean sent = false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `getContentAsPDF` call does not run within the transaction that it is called from. So if the calling transaction has not committed, and the `getContentAsPDF` call relies on data created in that transaction, it will not produce the expected result. This behaviour had been painful for us, with the general solution being to kickoff some asynchronous code to make the call as that is guaranteed to follow the commit.

I'm not sure how commits are handed in flows though, so this may or may not be the problem you are seeing.

Comment: The Case record and related records are not updated as part of the flow, prior to generating the PDF.  The concept is just to send a PDF rendering of the Case as it is at the moment the button is pushed.

Comment: Hi @MichaelSobczak not this then.

Comment: The answer was to move the method that generates the PDF and sends it to an @future(callout=true) method.